# Additional characters are coming during bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert the first row from a csv file into a table with only one column.
But I am getting some extra characters('n++') in the begining like this:

```
n++First Column;Second Column;Third Column;Fourth Column;Fifth Columnm;Sixth Column
```

CSV file contents are like:

```
First Column;Second Column;Third Column;Fourth Column;Fifth Columnm;Sixth Column
```

You can find the test.csv file [here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b4ah0h3/n/test.csv/)

And this is the code I am using to get the first row data in a table

```
declare @importSQL nvarchar(2000)
declare @tempstr varchar(max)
declare @path varchar(100)  

SET @path = 'D:\test.csv'    

CREATE TABLE #tbl (line VARCHAR(max))

SET @importSQL = 
'BULK INSERT #tbl 
FROM ''' + @path + ''' 
WITH ( 
LASTROW = 1,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)' 

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt=@importSQL 

SET @tempstr = (SELECT TOP 1 RTRIM(REPLACE(Line, CHAR(9), ';')) FROM #tbl)

print @tempstr
drop table #tbl
```

Any idea where this extra 'n++' is coming from?

Comment: I don't think TRIM exists. Does it?

Answer (score 4):

It seems UTF-8 files are not supported by SQL Server 2005 and 2008, it will only be available in version 11!

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/bulk-insert-and-bcp-does-not-recognize-codepage-65001

Comment: Seems like there is nothing like codepage = '65001' as msdn list of codepages doesn't have it for sql server 2005. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186356(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: I have reported this issue to microsoft feedback. Lets see what do they have to say.
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/631379/bulk-insert-reading-addional-text-byte-order-mark-of-the-file-from-csv-file-in-sql-server-2005#tabs

Answer (score 4):

The extra charectors are caused by the encoding. You can use used notepad to change the encoding format from UTF-8 to Unicode. This removed the 'n++' on the first row.

Answer (score 3):

It might be the [Unicode Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that are being picked up.

I suggest your try setting the `DATAFILETYPE` option as part of your statement.  See MSDN documentation for more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173832%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: Tried DATAFILETYPE = 'char' and DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'. But didn't help.

Comment: I also tried CODEPAGE='RAW' and n++ now changed to ï»¿ whcih is the BOM for UTF-8. But I am still not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Nadeem can you perhaps get the byte order mark using a Hex viewer on your file?

Comment: Well I tried PartCopy to see the hex code of the csv file. According to the hex code produced by it there is ï»¿ character before First Column. But the question still remanis how to avoid bulk insert to read this BOM.

Comment: Seems its is BOM for a UTF-8 file.  Please try DATAFILETYPE = 'char' and CODEPAGE='65001' to see if that works for you?

Comment: OK last try, DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar' and CODEPAGE='65001'

Comment: Try making the data type NVARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, Old SQL Server versions not supports utf-8. Add the codepage parameter to bulk insert method. In your question please change your code as exists.

```
SET @importSQL = 
'BULK INSERT #tbl 
    FROM ''' + @path + ''' 
    WITH ( LASTROW = 1, 
           FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
           ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' , 
           CODEPAGE=''65001'')'
```

Note that, your file must be in utf-8 format.
But the problem there is, if you're upgrade your server from 2005 to 2008 the codepage 65001(utf-8) not supported and then you will get the " codepage not supported"message

Comment: Is there a way to use this in SQL 2012?

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of SQL server you can add '-C 65001' to the command to tell it to use utf-8 encoding. This will remove the n++ from the first line. That is a capital C. Of course when you type the command don't include the quotes.